How can i resolve this error in Tortoise Git
git.exe add -f [...]
error: open("CRIMs/DEV/src/Lobby Elements/User Story 81248 PRICE_US Purchase Management/lobby/datasources/PRICE_CRESTRIDGE_AUTHORIZED_REQUISITIONS - 32c3dbf7-2ffa-4a7a-b776-fe52aedd3697.datasource.xml"): Filename too long
error: unable to index file 'CRIMs/DEV/src/Lobby Elements/User Story 81248 PRICE_US Purchase Management/lobby/datasources/PRICE_CRESTRIDGE_AUTHORIZED_REQUISITIONS - 32c3dbf7-2ffa-4a7a-b776-fe52aedd3697.datasource.xml'
fatal: adding files failed

git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128)
I was trying to commit a folder to the repository

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Filename+too+long

well, in the error it states your "Filename too long" so is there any chance you can reduce the file name to something shorter? if not then have a loot at what I found:
Git uses an older version of the Windows API and there's a limit of 260 characters for a filename. “longpaths = true” in the config file of our repo's git configuration file which then allows us to use the character limit of 4096 for the file name.
